# Fade divs in and out on jQuery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I have a few divs which are essentially just colorful rectangles to help visualize.  As I scroll down the page, each rectangle should `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` depending on scrollbar position.  Unfortunately, it freaks out and the fade comes off more as a spastic strobe light.  I think it would be better to determine the opacity level by how far along, scroll-wise, I am through each element, but I'm not even sure where to begin on that sillyness.

Seems [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462751/fade-out-on-scroll) had a similar question, but the answer didn't work.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruXeq/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $element_array = $("#content").find("div");
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $element_array.each (function(){
            if (($(this).position().top + $(this).height()) < $(window).scrollTop())
                $(this).fadeIn();
            if (($(this).position().top + $(this).height()) > $(window).scrollTop())
                $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="bg1"></div>
    <div id="bg2"></div>
    <div id="bg3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{height:100%;margin:0;}
#content{
    background:#333333;
    height:2000px;
    z-index:1;
}
#bg1{
    background:blue;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    display: none;
}
#bg2{
    background:green;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:3;
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    display: none;
}
#bg3{
    background:red;
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:4;
    position:fixed;
    top:300px;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You've got a few problems here

One problem problem is is that `$(this).position().top` is returning 0 for each of the divs (due to their fixed nature).  You need to parse the actual css value.

The second is in the nature of the functions `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.  If you call `fadeOut()` on an item that is faded out, it will lag behind if one scrolls agressively on your page.  *But I have not addressed that issue below*.

I also put `else` after the first `if` because the code paths (should) be mutually exclusive.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $element_array = $("#content").find("div");
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $element_array.each (function(){
            if ((parseInt($(this).css('top')) + $(this).height()) < $(window).scrollTop())
                $(this).fadeIn();
            else if ((parseInt($(this).css('top')) + $(this).height()) > $(window).scrollTop())
                $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Although you didn't address lag that occurs due to aggressive scrolling (something I'm not concerned about at the moment), your solution did solve my particular problem.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `$(window).scroll()` handler is executed for every time you click and scroll down the page, so you are pushing a **ton** of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` calls onto [jQuery's animation queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me).  The solution is to have something in the `if` statement that is checking whether or not the fade is already happening, and if so prevent adding another animation to the queue, so something *roughly* like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $element_array = $("#content").find("div");
    var fades = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $element_array.each (function(){
            if (($(this).position().top + $(this).height()) < $(window).scrollTop() && (fades == 0))
                $(this).fadeIn(function(){fades = 1;});
            if (($(this).position().top + $(this).height()) > $(window).scrollTop() && (fades > 0))
                $(this).fadeOut(function(){ fades = 0; });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruXeq/4/

Comment: This works nice when `fadeOut` is called, but all 3 elements `fadeIn` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the + height() thing from the fadeOut condition because it makes no sense there

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var remember = 0;
    var $element_array = $("#content").find("div");
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        $element_array.each (function(){
            if (($(this).position().top+ $(this).height()) < $(window).scrollTop()){
                $(this).fadeIn();}
            if (($(this).position().top ) > $(window).scrollTop())
                $(this).fadeOut();
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruXeq/5/

and it will work like a vanilla ice

Comment: This works nice when `fadeOut` is called, but all 3 elements `fadeIn` at the same time.